# Unioned table costs more to query in BigQuery than individual tables?

Tags: google-bigquery, database-partitioning, database-cluster

BigQuery cost scenarios

[image: 1]

When I query a large unioned table - partitioned by date field and clustered by a clientkey field - for a specific client's data it appears to process *more* data than if I just queried that client table individually. Same query, should be the exact same data from different tables; massively different cost.

Does anyone know why it costs more to query a partitioned/clustered unioned table compared to the same data from the individual client-specific table?

I'm trying to make the case for still keeping this data unioned and partitioned+clustered as opposed to individual datasets! Thanks!

Comment: how many individual tables you have? i am trying to correlate 3 [tables] vs. 100 [cost increase]?

Comment: Are you using BI engine and one result is too big and doesn't fit? and the other fits so its costs less?

Comment: Usually clustering key is not 1:1 boxed to client_id, so under one clustering key, you might have multiple clients. Clustering is not index, it's more shards. It's a box-in-box construction.

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant there are >100 individual tables

Comment: @Pentium10 maybe this is getting at my problem...

so in this scenario where I have a large table w/ multiple clients, clustered by client_name field, and I SELECT * FROM UNIONED_TABLE WHERE client_name = 'Client A'

I assumed that this^ should process ~same amount of data as just querying the client-specific table...bc in the large unioned table, BQ would scan clustered client_name field and only process data for 'Client A'

Am I wrong here?

Comment: you are correct, it scans the cluster (with multiple client entries)

Answer (score 0):

There is factor which may affect your scenario, however, the factor is not a contract so this answer may be irrelevant over time.

The assumptions are:

1. the partitioned table is clustered
2. the individual table is also clustered
3. the query utilized clustering and touched only small amount of data (comparing with the cluster block size)

In such case, the cluster block size might affect the cost. Since the individual table is much smaller than the partitioned table, the individual table tends to have smaller cluster block size. The query is eventually charged by the combined size of blocks getting scanned.

Comment: thanks for feedback...maybe this is getting at my problem... 

so in this scenario where I have a large unioned table w/ multiple clients, clustered by client_name field, and I SELECT * FROM UNIONED_TABLE WHERE client_name = 'Client A' 

I assumed that this^ should process ~same amount of data as just querying the client-specific table...bc in the large unioned table, BQ would scan clustered client_name field and only process data for 'Client A' 

Am I wrong here?

Comment: The difference is on `cluster block size`. Just use an extreme example, `WHERE client_name='A' AND a_unique_id=<id>` will match one row and you are charged of scanning  of one cluster block. Larger block size means larger scanning size here.